# How to set Title for Koa Community Template Winter '16

Tags: lightning-community, koa

I am not able to find how to change the Title for our community site. The browser tab just shows Koa Template Title when you load up the site, then the salesforce favicon + (Page Title) after a few seconds.

[image]

Comment: did you find an answer to override the default title. If not I have something close but do not think you can suppress it. The KOA Title loads by default and there is a JS file from salesforce(aura) that replaces your custom title. I know you can override css but JS cannot be messed with in communities

Answer (score 4):

According to Salesforce Support this functionality is by design and there is no known workaround. I recommend voting for the following Idea and hope that Salesforce takes action:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DvgQAAS

Answer (score 0):

Could not be an answer but I have no option to show images in the comments:

My community is on KOA

[image]

I am able to set my custom page title from the Property Editor for the page

click on the page drop down choose the desired page: click on the pages symbol

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the page title set also. It only shows Koa Template Title for about 2-3 seconds then displays the Page Title defined in Community Builder. My question was not specific to that. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You will have to do it via JavaScript.

Comment: Can you please provide more information or maybe a solution of how that can be done?

Comment: I have checked internally and confirmed this is not possible at the moment.